# Laravel queue ordering in configuration

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I know that queue in jobs is where you set the priority of the job, like when I run the command and specifying the queue ordering like this:

`php artisan queue:listen --queue=High,Mid,Low`

But in Laravel queue config `queue.php` file there is a queue key in every driver array, i.e:

```
    'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            // this one
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
```

What this have to do with jobs? I've never seen someone changing this! I am not seeing exactly what it is or what it has to do with the jobs in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues),  what the effect of changing this? and can it be an array of queues or just a string?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this;

```
Queue::pushOn('high', new FooJob());
```

It is going to push into the queue named `high`. You may change it to `mid` or `low`. If your queue driver is redis, then it is going to be like these after you push them.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "queues:high"
2) "queues:low"
3) "queues:mid"
```

If you want to consume these queues you need to execute the following command as you already mentioned;

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=High,Mid,Low
```

If you don't explicitly define any `queue` while pushing such as;

```
Queue::push(new FooJob());
Queue::later(86400, new FooJob());
```

then it is going to use the `default` as default since you didn't explicitly define it while pushing.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "queues:default"
2) "queues:default:delayed"
```

Then you may execute only to listen default queues.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

For your last question, it has to be string. This is the method from `RedisQueue` class.

```
/**
 * Get the queue or return the default.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $queue
 * @return string
 */
protected function getQueue($queue)
{
    return 'queues:'.($queue ?: $this->default);
}
```

Comment: Yea I know all about this stuff, I am asking about the queue in the conf file. what is its goal?
is it just to specifying the default queue to run if I don't specify one? just?

Comment: @shamaseen yes, it is used for both pushing and consuming while not explicitly specified the name.